# One Django view and url, multiple apps

Tags: django, ajax, django-views, django-urls

I have a small newsletter signup form at the footer of every page. The footer is part of `base.html`.

I use Ajax to submit the form. Right now Ajax code calls a view defined in `app1` and the corresponding URL is defined in the `urls.py` of the same app.

Here's the AJAX code (this code is saved in a separate `js` file and included in the `base.html`):

```
$('#newsletterForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    $('#loader').css("display", "block")

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/subscribe/",
        data : {
            subscriber_email : $('#e-mail').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrftoken,
            datatype : "json",
        },

        success: function(){
            $('#loader').css("display", "none"),
            $('#subscribed').css("display", "block"),
            $('#subscribed').delay(3000).fadeOut("slow")
        },

        failure: function(){
            alert('An error has occurred. Please try again.')
        },
    });
});
```

The view (defined in app1):

```
def subscribe(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        subscriber = Subscriber(email=request.POST.get('subscriber_email'))
        subscriber.save()
        return JsonResponse({}, status=200)
    else:
        return redirect('homepage:index')
```

The URL (defined in app1):

```
    path('subscribe/', views.subscribe, name='subscribe'),
```

Now, the problem is when I'm in `app2`, Django looks for `/subscribe/` in that app which doesn't exist.
So is there any way to solve this issue by including the `appname` in the `url` of AJAX code? or I have to include `/subscribe/` in `urls.py` and `views.py` of every app?

Comment: could you show the `error code` and main `urls.py`

Comment: The error code is ```404``` because ```/subscribe/``` is only defined in ```app1``` but I'm also calling it from ```app2``` and ```app3```. I tried ```url : {% url 'app1:subscribe' %}``` in my AJAX code but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand your problem. Do you want to use the same url in app1 in app2? If this is your request, as far as I know, such a thing is not possible because a related views function is connected to each url in the urls.py file.

-- UPDATED --

As I understand you want to make the URL field in the AJAX code dynamic. This is how I solve this problem. I either add an attribute to the form tag or add a hidden input field within the form field and bring the relevant url from the views function to the html file related to the context and add it to one of the fields I specified, and finally, I take the value of the relevant attribute or input field by javascript and assign it to the url information of the AJAX code.

Comment: I want my AJAX code to submit the form to the ```/subscribe/``` URL and view of ```app1``` even if it is called from ```app2``` or ```app3```.

Comment: As I understand you want to make the URL field in the AJAX code dynamic. This is how I solve this problem. I either add an attribute to the form tag or add a hidden input field within the form field and bring the relevant url from the views function to the html file related to the context and add it to one of the fields I specified, and finally, I take the value of the relevant attribute or input field by javascript and assign it to the url information of the AJAX code. .

Comment: Ok, i did it. @OmidShojaee